# AspectJ - Load time weaving on java.net.Socket trouble

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, aspectj

Source:

```
package net.andrewewhite.aspects;
import java.util.ArrayList;


import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;

@Aspect
public class SocketProfiler {

    @Around("call(* java.net.Socket.connect(..)) || execution(* java.net.Socket.connect(..))")
    public void SocketRead(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {



         long time=0;
         Object rt=null;
             time= System.nanoTime();
            joinPoint.proceed();

            time=(System.nanoTime()-time)/1000;
            com.profile.Profiler.socketRead.add(time);


        }

}
```

aop.xml

```
<aspectj>
<aspects>
    <aspect name="net.andrewewhite.aspects.SocketProfiler"/>
  </aspects>
  <weaver options="-verbose -Xset:weaveJavaxPackages=true -Xset:weaveJavaPackages=true">
  </weaver>
 </aspectj>
```

### Vm Args

```
-javaagent:D:\tools\aspectJn\lib\aspectjweaver.jar  (on eclipse ide)
```

It works if i try to weaving the calls to system.out.println. But when i try Java.net.Socket it doesn't. Any help in regard appreciated.

Comment: can you please post the verbose output?

Answer (score 4):

Actually I have no problems weaving `call(Socket.connect)`, but `execution(Socket.connect)` is another story altogether, because

- `call(Socket.connect)` matches join points in your client code, i.e. all the places in your code where the method is called,
- `execution(Socket.connect)` matches join points in JDK code, but JDK packages `java` and `javax` are excluded from weaving by default.

This seems to be the day on which I stumble upon this type of questions (or similar), so you may want to read my answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12071937/1082681) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12064531/1082681) for further information.

Comment: How did you get `call(Socket.connect)` working?  I couldn't get Aspectj to do LTW on JDK packages.

Comment: @stackoverflower: As I said, JDK packages are only a problem with `execution()` pointcuts, but not with `call()` as long as you weave into your own code where the calls happen. Read my original answer carefully and not the details of my explanation.

Comment: OMG, I mean: **note** the the details of my explanation. Sorry for the typo.