# Spring 3.0 / AOP / Aspectj:autoproxy intercept any call to getConnection()

Tags: spring, connection, aop, aspectj

I'm trying to intercept any call to getConnection() method to setup the dbms indentifier . I've implemented an aspect to get it but I don't get anything. Any idea? Thanks!

```
import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.sql.Connection;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterReturning;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestAttributes;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder;

import es.iberia.tryp.model.entities.Usuario;

@Component
@Aspect
public class ConnectionAspect {

    @AfterReturning(value = "execution(java.sql.Connection javax.sql.DataSource+.getConnection(..))", returning = "connection")
    //@AfterReturning(value = "execution(java.sql.Connection org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.*.*(*))", returning = "connection")
    //@AfterReturning(value = "execution(java.sql.Connection java.sql.Connection *(..))", returning = "connection")
    //@AfterReturning(value = "execution(java.sql.Connection org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.*(..))", returning = "connection")

    public void prepare (Connection connection) throws Throwable {

        HttpSession httpSession = (HttpSession) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes().resolveReference(RequestAttributes.REFERENCE_SESSION);

        if (httpSession!=null && (Usuario)httpSession.getAttribute("usuario")!=null && ((String)((Usuario)httpSession.getAttribute("usuario")).getNomina())!=null) {
            String nomina = (String)((Usuario)httpSession.getAttribute("usuario")).getNomina();
            String prepSql = "{ call DBMS_SESSION.SET_IDENTIFIER('" + nomina +"') }";
            CallableStatement cs = connection.prepareCall(prepSql);                             
            cs.execute();
            cs.close();         
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I have an idea: Actually your pointcuts match the desired calls, but they are in the **java** package which (like the **javax** package) is excluded from weaving by default.

There is a way to remove that restriction via [command line](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=149261#c11) and [aop.xml](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/devguide/ltw-configuration.html), but please be aware of potential problems concerning classloading. You have to make sure the classloader loading the java classes has a [weaver attached](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=149261#c13), so if you have the option not to use LTW, just weave the JDK class files and use those woven classes, and you will be fine. Otherwise you might have a "hen and egg" problem.

Answer (score 3):

Check whether you have added the below tag in your xml file.

aop:aspectj-autoproxy

Also check whether you have added the bean definition inside the xml for this ConnectionAspect class.