# How to hijacked/intercept method of a class which from third party(EclipseLink) jar or even JDK?

Tags: spring, aop, aspectj

I try to hijack/intercept a method of a class in EclipseLink. I had tried Spring AOP and AspectJ and I failed. I want to do something when class `org.eclipse.persistence.internal.localization.i18n.TraceLocalizationResource` throw exception while calling method `getString(..);` My implementation as below:

```
@AfterThrowing(pointcut = "execution(* org.eclipse.persistence.internal.localization.i18n.TraceLocalizationResource.getString(..))",throwing="error")
    public void logAfterThrowing(JoinPoint joinPoint,Throwable error) {
....
}
```

And calss`TraceLocalizationResource` was called (I debug into it). But the hijack method wasn't called.

MY questions:

1. Was I doing it in the wrong way ?
2. The target class we want to hijack or intercept must be self-define type?
3. What if I want to hijack a class in JDK like java.lang.String ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Basically the syntax looks okay, but I have not tried to replicate a
   full aspect from your code snippet here. Furthermore, I only use
   native AspectJ syntax and am not quite familiar with
   annotation-based syntax, so if there is a problem there I might not
   have seen it.
2. No, but if you want to weave a library (JAR or unpacked into the file system) used by your main application, you must make sure that it is in the in-path for the weaver. Please consult AspectJ documentation for the syntax. **Edit:** I posted some helpful links in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12064531/1082681) earlier today.
3. By default, packages `org.aspectj`, `java` and `javax` are excluded from weaving. For the latter two, there are command line switches to enable weaving. But LTW will be tricky at best and a pain in the a** (next to impossible) at worst because you have a hen-and-egg problem there: The AspectJ weaver runtime classes need the JDK, and JDK bootstrapping happens before any Java agent like the weaver is attached. So your best bet is compile-time weaving for JDK classes and then using the woven rt.jar later in your application. Even with compile-time weaving you might run into issues if your advice use JDK woven classes themselves. You want to make sure to avoid infinite recursions there. But it is possible.

   **Update:** Another hint which sometimes seems too simple to mention for someone who has used AspectJ for a while: Instead of an `execution` pointcut which makes it necessary to weave the target class, you may just use a `call` pointcut which intercepts (as the name implies) calls to the target everywhere in your client classes. It might be a little less efficient, but maybe your best and easiest bet unless you really want to take the trouble of weaving the JDK.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to weave third party libraries but you must configure the aspectj-maven-plugin plugin:

```
<project>
  ...
  <dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
      <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
      <version>1.8.9</version>
    </dependency>

     <dependency>
      <groupId>org.agroup</groupId>
      <artifactId>to-weave</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.anothergroup</groupId>
      <artifactId>gen</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    ...
  </dependencies>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.9</version>
        <configuration>
          <weaveDependencies>
            <weaveDependency>
              <groupId>org.agroup</groupId>
              <artifactId>to-weave</artifactId>
            </weaveDependency>
            <weaveDependency>
              <groupId>org.anothergroup</groupId>
              <artifactId>gen</artifactId>
            </weaveDependency>
          </weaveDependencies>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      ...
    </plugins>
  <build>
  ...
</project>
```

Source: http://www.mojohaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin/examples/weaveJars.html